# Propper way to deinitialize GTK

Tags: c++, gtk, x11

I'm writing a c++ application that creates a GTK3 window at some point, while also running X11 code in other places.

For the pure X11 part i'm using `XOpenDisplay()` to open a display.

Running the X11 part and opening a GTK window afterwards works fine. Also running the X11 part multiple times is no problem as i release the display there using `XCloseDisplay`.

The problem i'm facing occurs when i try to run the X11 code *after* gtk has been initialized (to be more specific, calling `XOpenDisplay()` after the gtk initialization).

I'm suspecting that after running `gtk_init()` the display is never being released, even after `gtk_main_quit()`.

I didn't find anything about deinitialization in the gtk3 documentation. Is there any way to propperly deinitialize gtk or free the display in another way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was completely unrelated. I was setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable twice by accident. Apparently gtk can handle this but `XOpenDisplay` crashes.

I have added a test to only set it once, now everything works. Perhaps gtk does propperly deinitialize after `gtk_main_quit()`